# what are rails g XXXXX:install ? for example how rails g bootstrap:install works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering when you run

```
rails g xxxxxxx:install
```

what happens ? what are these xxxxx (for example I know bootstrap but what does bootstrap:install do as I anyway have included bootstrap gem). Does these install create the files or do something more internally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rails g` is a shortcut for `rails generate`. There are some baked-in generators in rails (`rails g migration` for example) that indeed can create files or change your configuration.

Anyone can write their own generators:  see the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) for more information.

**EDIT**

generators, like rake task, can be namespaced. So `bootstrap:install` will invoke the install generator in the bootstrap namespace, which, [according to the docs](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails), installs the required css files in your asset folder. If you want more details, just [read the generator code](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)...

Comment: Thanks, I know about generators, but what is xxxxx:install do ? it installs that generator ?